# In /review, my vote is not shown

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, user-interface, review

I'm in `/review`, and I click on `review question` or `review answer` to expand a post. Even if I've previously voted this post up or down, this fact is not shown, I only see black vote arrows. If I do click on a vote arrow, then the usual pop-up appear to tell me that I've already voted, and the arrow corresponding to my vote becomes orange (in the SO color scheme).

[image: In /review: no vote shown]        
[image: On the question page: I have voted]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know when this happened, but I noticed it's been fixed. If I see a post in `/review`, open it in another tab, vote on it, then expand it in `/review`, I see my vote.